# RUSAGE_SELF returns memory usage in bytes?

Tags: python

I am still not very clear about the unit of RUSAGE_SELF after going through the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) of Python resource.

What actually RUSAGE_SELF returns? Memory usage of the whole program in bytes?

```
resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss
```

What exactly is the unit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes CPython documentation needs to be used in conjunction with the C documentation, since CPython builds on C.  In this case, you might find what you need in http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage - or perhaps the getrusage doc for some other *ix variant.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

**It depends on your system unfortunately.**

On Linux, it appears to be kilobytes. On OXS/Darwin/Apple, it appears to be bytes.

https://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage

[what does "ru_maxrss" means in getrusage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097783/what-does-ru-maxrss-means-in-getrusage)