# what does "ru_maxrss" means in getrusage

Tags: c++, memory-management, getrusage

I compiled and run the following c++ code `test.cpp` on my macOS Sierra.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/resource.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    struct rusage r_usage;
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &r_usage);
    cout << "Memory usage = " << r_usage.ru_maxrss << endl;
    int b = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Then got:

```
➜  Desktop git:(master) ✗ ./test
Memory usage = 663552
```

Then I found the unit of `ru_maxrss` is **kilobytes** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050913/whats-the-unit-of-ru-maxrss-on-linux), so the program used **663552 kilobytes**? But I only just created an integer.

Another question is: does `ru_maxrss` count `int b = 2`? or it just counts the memory usage before the line calling `ru_maxrss`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under OSX, the unit is bytes.

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getrusage.2.html